# My form requires additional data, where should I put my routes and controller methods to get it?

Tags: laravel, rest, routes, controller

I'm learning how to create web application with laravel and I don't know correct way to create struct for this example form:

I have simple controller named i.e. **PostController** with methods:
`index()`, `create()`, `store()`, `show()`, `edit()`, `update()`, `destroy()`
created via `make:controller --resource`.
And I have routes for it in my **web.php** file created via `Route::resource()` method.

Now, my `create()` method in **PostController** display a form for create new post, but this form required select an option from list.
I can't display whole list because it's thousands of options do I want create search field which use ajax to get available options from my database. Then user just select an option and can send form.

It's ofcourse just example but in that situation where should I put my method controller and route for search options?
Should I crate additional method in my **PostControlle**r ( i.e. searchOption( $string  ) ) or should it be new controller?
If it should be new controller then do you have any suggestion for folder/name structure for it?
And where should I put my routes for it? Still in **web.php**? or **api.php**?
And again, how should I name this route?

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinse you have another entity you can make another controller. Let's say you want filtered `City` in your `Post`'s create view.

```
// Controllers/Api/CityController.php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = City::query();

    if ($request->has('search')) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $request->input('search') . '%');
    }      

    $cities = $query->paginate();

    return response()->json(['cities' => $cities]);
}
```